# Failed to build apk for flutter apps

Tags: flutter, build, package, apk

I am trying to build my apps in android.. when I run in debug mode, it seems ok and runs well, but when I try to `flutter build apk` there are error like this

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      55.6s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using
Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin camera...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                 1,867ms
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin disk_space...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                 2,303ms
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin firebase_ml_vision...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                 1,132ms


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Cannot find a version of 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
        Dependency path 'io.flutter.plugins.firebasemlvision:firebase_ml_vision:1.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
```

is there something that I should add for configuration?

Comment: flutter build apk --debug,flutter build apk --profile,flutter build apk --release

Comment: Can not build in release mode, is there something that I should add ? @M.M.Hasibuzzaman